# QtMultimedia on Raspbian

Tags: linux, qt

I tried to deploy an application Qt on Raspbian (in raspberry pi 3).

```
Qt Creator 3.2.1
Based on Qt 5.3.2 (GCC 4.9.2, 32 bit)
Debuggers: System GDB at /usr/bin/gdb/bin/gdb GDB
Compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.9
Qt Version: Qt 5.3.2 (qt5) /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmake
```

I have a problem when I want execute my application :

```
Error: Could not load: qrc:/main.qml:7 module "QtMultimedia" is not installed
```

Line 7:

```
import QtMultimedia 5.0
```

I use camera in qml.

```
Camera {
         id: camera
         imageProcessing.whiteBalanceMode: 
         CameraImageProcessing.WhiteBalanceFlash
```

My app.pro:

```
Qt += multimedia
```

I install:

```
qtdeclarative5-dev, qtmobility-dev, qtdeclarative5-qtmultimedia-plugin
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev libdbus-1-dev libfreetype6-dev libudev-dev libicu-dev libsqlite3-dev libxslt1-dev libssl-dev libasound2-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev \
libswscale-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev gstreamer-tools gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad libraspberrypi-dev libpulse-dev \
libx11-dev libglib2.0-dev libcups2-dev freetds-dev libsqlite0-dev libpq-dev libiodbc2-dev libmysqlclient-dev firebird-dev libpng12-dev libjpeg9-dev libgst-dev libxext-dev libxcb1 \
libxcb1-dev libx11-xcb1 libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-image0 libxcb-image0-dev libxcb-shm0 libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-icccm4-dev \
libxcb-sync0 libxcb-sync1-dev libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-render-util0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxrender-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxi-dev libdrm-dev gstreamer0.10-alsa
```

But I have same error.

Comment: what is your code?

Comment: I use "Camera" in qml.